# AS3 : Save part of movieclip as png

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, flash, air

I am using LeeBurrows/Async-Image-Encoders library to save movie clip to sdcard.
My movie clip size is 1080 X 1920.
here is my code:

```
        myBitmapData = new BitmapData(1079, 1500, true, 0x00000000);
        encoder = new AsyncPNGEncoder();

        myBitmapData.draw(movieClip1);
        encoder.start(myBitmapData, 40);
```

The Code works fine, image is saved in 1080 X 1920 size.
But how to save the part of the movie clip.
For example starting from point (50, 50) and in size of 400 X 600 resultin the rectangle as (50, 50, 400, 600).

Comment: the draw method of BitmapData also accepts a matrix as an optional parameter. Perform a translate operation on the matrix and pass it in the function call.

Answer (score 0):

Use a crop function like this.

```
public function crop( _x:Number, _y:Number, _width:Number, _height:Number, displayObject:DisplayObject = null):Bitmap
{
   var cropArea:Rectangle = new Rectangle( 0, 0, _width, _height );
   var croppedBitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap( new BitmapData( _width, _height ), PixelSnapping.ALWAYS, true );
   croppedBitmap.bitmapData.draw( (displayObject!=null) ? displayObject : stage, new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -_x, -_y) , null, null, cropArea, true );
   return croppedBitmap;
}
```